# Split a number into 2 parts: above and below a given number N

Tags: java, python, math

I am trying to model electricity costs. Usually, for <1000 kWh usage, there is a certain per-kwh cost, which increases if you use >1000kWh a month.  I need a single equation that gives the cost per kWh, given a [particular model for electricity consumption](http://reliant.com/files/0901751880ec0ea3.pdf).

Given number x and a constant N, find a and b where:

- a = the portion of the number below N
- b = portion of number above N

"if" conditions cannot be used; a single formula is needed.

#### For example:

- For `N=1000` and `x=500`, we have `a=500, b=0`.
- For `N=1000` and `x=1500`, we have `a=1000, b=500`.

#### Edit:

To make it more clear:

- for x < N, a = x mod N, b = 0;
- for x > N, a = N, b = x mod N.

#### Edit2:

`abs()` operator is acceptable, since it can be implemented using bit operators. `abs(x)=((x >>> 30) | 1)) * x`.

How can the two cases be combined into a single equation?

Comment: Would you make it more clear? I am confusing between x and N?

Comment: Aren't you talking about "subtraction"?

Comment: Some advice to a new StackOverflow user: Posts need to be programming related. It's important to have a question that can actually be answered. Also, it's good to show what attempts you've made on your own so far - SO is not here for people to do work for you.

Comment: This should not be here, but on http://math.stackexchange.com/ (Even there it’s a laughable question, but at least it would be placed thematically correct there.)

Comment: @lurker: not really - I am trying to model electricity costs. Usually, for <1000 kWh usage, there is a certain per-kwh cost, which increases if you use >1000kWh a month.

Comment: @HotLicks: No. You cannot use conditional operators. Free to use mod/floor/ceil/log etc. though.

Comment: @Kache: I tried using a = x-N*floor(x/N), but the solution doesn't hold for x > N.

Comment: It can be done (for positive numbers) using floor.

Comment: @CBroe: Not sure why it is laughable, given that you cannot use conditional operators.

Comment: (But one wonders what the point is.)

Comment: @HotLicks: basically, I need a single equation that gives the cost per kWh, given the following electricity model: https://www.reliant.com/files/0901751880ec0ea3.pdf .

Comment: _“given that you cannot use conditional operators”_ – well then you should say what _can_ be used – because you have not even told us what programming language or environment you want to do this in, but merely tagged it with `Math` … _“How can the two cases be combined into a single equation?”_ – that absolutely depends on what kind of _operators_ you have available.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: @user2698 tag it with programming language of choice

Comment: @user2698-Please feel free to comment OR else accept the answer as we have combinedly solve the question! Hurray!!!

Comment: *"if" conditions cannot be used; a single formula is needed.* Why does this constraint exist?

Comment: @lurker: so that I can model it mathematically?

Comment: When you enter a nonlinearity into your equation, it becomes much more difficult to "model mathematically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got one after support from defintion of max version provided by you---

`max(a,b) = 1/2 (a+b+abs(a-b))`

and a minimum defintion from myside

`min(a,b) = 1/2 (a+b-abs(a-b))` .

Please improve me wherever I am wrong by criticising :-

```
b={x-N+abs(x-N)}/2;
a={x+N-abs(x-N)}/2;     Or    simply, x-b;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python

```
(a,b) = (min(x,N), max(x-N,0))
```

Comment: Oh,but these functions do utilise if-else!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman: Since OP mentioned `floor` already, we can likely assume that some kind of math library with common functions including `min` and `max` is available.

Comment: it would be good to get clarification from the OP

Comment: No,SIR---Not any kind of math library like `min,max` which involves if-else is acceptable---@CBroe. Not at any cost,it is against this question's rule! One must try to achieve this logically!

Comment: @shekharsuman You seem to have very definite views on this -- are you a fellow student with the same assignment or the professor who set it?

Comment: I'll accept abs() operator, which can be implemented using bit operators. max(a,b) = 1/2 (a+b+abs(a-b))

Comment: No @TooTone---I am just the student which accepts challenges and never tries to cheat the professor or others unlike someone present here!

Comment: @shekharsuman fair play to you then, and perhaps I shouldn't have answered. In any case it seems like the OP your fellow student has solved the challenge by defining his/her own version of `max` (I came up with a similar-looking definition of `min`), so the problem can be conceived of as "done" to all intents and purposes.

Comment: @user2698 if you can define `min`, which can also be done using `abs` you are done.

Comment: @TooTone-Neither is OP my fellow mate or neither my friend, and obviously you shouldn't have answered because `min()`,`max()` directly uses if-else statement or conditional operations!

Comment: Go to CodeGolf... They love such tricky things :)

Comment: @shekharsuman I'm afraid defining `min` and `max` in terms of `abs` is a bit too much like code golf for me!

Comment: @TooTone-Without any ill-will please check my answer and then comment as to what you feel about the question AND my answer (// here I am using AND operator---ha ha ha)...

Comment: @shekharsuman I think it works, well done! However avoiding the simplest solution, even if specified by the question, makes me go uuuuuuuuuuuuugh! :)

Comment: @TooTone-Though I agree with you,but,my brother,sometimes we need to bind ourselves within given constraints! BTW, thanks for encouraging me to solve this problem!